# Using R to compare two words and find letters unique to second word (across c. 6000 cases)

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe comprising two columns of words. For each row I'd like to identify any letters that occur in only the word in the second column e.g.

```
carpet    carpelt        #return 'l'
bag       flag           #return 'f' & 'l'
dog       dig            #return 'i'
```

I'd like to use R to do this automatically as I have 6126 rows.

As an R newbie, the best I've got so far is this, which gives me the unique letters across both words (and is obviously very clumsy):

```
x<-(strsplit("carpet", ""))
y<-(strsplit("carpelt", ""))
z<-list(l1=x, l2=y)
unique(unlist(z))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you wanted to split all your words at once you could just pass the whole vector of words to `strsplit`, as it is vectorised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you’re searching for is [`setdiff`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sets.html):

```
chars_for = function (str)
    strsplit(str, '')[[1]]

result = setdiff(chars_for(word2), chars_for(word1))
```

(Note the inverted order of the arguments in `setdiff`.)

To apply it to the whole `data.frame`, called `x`:

```
apply(x, 1, function (words) setdiff(chars_for(words[2]), chars_for(words[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex :) Paste your word with brackets [] and then use replace function for regex. This regex finds any letter from those in brackets and replaces it with empty string (you can say that it "removes" these letters).

```
require(stringi)
x <- c("carpet","bag","dog")
y <- c("carplet", "flag", "smog")
pattern <- stri_paste("[",x,"]")
pattern
## [1] "[carpet]" "[bag]"    "[dog]"   
stri_replace_all_regex(y, pattern, "")
## [1] "l"  "fl" "sm"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("carpet","bag","dog")
y <- c("carpelt", "flag", "dig")
```

Following (somewhat) with what you were going for with `strsplit`, you could do

```
> sx <- strsplit(x, "")
> sy <- strsplit(y, "")
> lapply(seq_along(sx), function(i) sy[[i]][ !sy[[i]] %in% sx[[i]] ])
#[[1]]
#[1] "l"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "f" "l"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "i"
```

This uses `%in%` to logically match the characters in `y` with the characters in `x`.  I negate the matching with `!` to determine those those characters that are in `y` but not in `x`.